# Spotfire built-in function: "Could not find function" error

Tags: function, syntax-error, spotfire

I have been having a number of issues using supposedly built in functions in Spotfire. When I try to use them in an expression then click OK to save it, I get an error telling me it can't find the function. Here is one example (DateDiff function works fine, but DateTimeNow does not):

My expression: `DateDiff("dd",[TimeFrame],DateTimeNow())`

Error:

> "Could not find function: 'DateTimeNow'"

My Spotfire build is 6.5.2.21.

According to the manual, this function exists. I can't see anything that indicates that I need to add in libraries, nor can I find any place to do so, so not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Spotfire Manual Page: http://stn.spotfire.com/spotfire_client_help/ncfe/ncfe_date_and_time_functions.htm

What am I missing to make these functions work?

Answer (score 0):

if you have added your data table as a "data connection" (as shown in [Opening Data from Database](http://stn.spotfire.com/spotfire_client_help/load/load_opening_data_from_a_database.htm)) you'll have this problem.

I saw this when adding data in this way (it was an MSSQL data source), and we resolved it by creating an info link instead of a connection. alternatively, export the data as a CSV and add it to Spotfire.

Comment: Is it still the only workaround, or has it been fixed for newer version of Spotfire (7.13 in my case) ?

Comment: It’s not really a workaround but a fundamental Spotfire concept. When adding data via OP’s method, you are limited to functions and aggregations provided by the database software versus when loading it via Info Designer, you can use Spotfire’s full range of the same. Check out these two links from TIBCO: https://www.tibco.com/resources/whitepaper/memory-analytical-systems-perspective-trade-offs-and-implementation and https://www.tibco.com/resources/whitepaper/database-analytical-systems-perspective-trade-offs-and-implementation